# PHP not writing to first SQL field

Tags: php, mysql

Thank you guys, worked it out, turns out it was in the js a word wasn't spelled correctly, always something simple

This is my script to write data to my database on my local server, it currently only writes to 2 fields, not the alias one, have I done anything wrong? I've triple checked the names in both the html form and the database field.

```
<?php
  // 1. Create connection to database

  mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Could not connect to mysql: <hr>'.mysql_error());

  // 2. Select database

  mysql_select_db("trialdb") or die('Could not connect to database:<hr>'.mysql_error());

  // 3. Assign variables (after connection as required by escape string)

$alias = $_POST['alias'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

  // 4. Insert data into table

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_data (alias, name, email) VALUES ('$alias', '$name', '$email')"); 
  Echo 'Your information has been successfully added to the database.';  
  print_r($_POST);
  mysql_close()
?>
```

Comment: did you check if `$_POST[]` variables return values

Comment: 1; Don't use `mysql_query`. 2; Certainly don't inject `$_POST` verbatim into a query. 3; Have you tried echoing out the query that it's going to run? See that you actually have values in `$_POST` and also gives you the chance to execute straight on the DB.

Comment: What does the output of print_r($_POST) give you?

Comment: What is after print_r($_POST) and which type is 'alias' field?

Comment: I guess you misspelled something

Comment: Also check that your table column names are all properly named and typed.

Comment: If it inserts all but `alias`, I'm curious as the the DB structure and wondering if something about how the field is defined is `auto_increment` or something of the sort.

Comment: @shannonman i think table column name are properly type because if not. the other 2 values will not be insert and else produces a sql error

Comment: Please make sure you read and understand [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: When I say typed I meant the type of column, would be helpful to see the structure of your table.

Comment: @shannonman oh i misread it im sorry .. lol

Comment: Try an error checking into your `$_POST[]` variables to see if each of them returns values.

Comment: No worries I could have wrote that better haha.

Comment: Thank you guys, worked it out, turns out it was in the js a word wasn't spelled correctly, always something simple!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should always check if the `POST` variables are being sent correctly:

```
if (
    !isset($_POST['alias']) or
    !isset($_POST['name']) or
    !isset($_POST['email'])
) // something is wrong
```

Second, you don't want to inject user input directly into the sql query. You should perform some escaping first (or even better replace the `mysql_*` deprecated drivers with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and just use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/493122)):

```
$alias = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['alias']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Third, you may want to check if the query performed correctly before printing a success message:

```
$res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_data (alias, name, email) VALUES ('$alias', '$name', '$email')"); 

echo ($res) 
    ? 'Your information has been successfully added to the database.' 
    : 'Your information couldn't be added to the database';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Could not connect to mysql: '.mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("trialdb", $conn) or die('Could not connect to database:'.mysql_error());

$alias = $_POST['alias'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_data (`alias`, `name`, `email`) VALUES ('$alias', '$name', '$email')", $conn); 

echo 'Your information has been successfully added to the database.';  

print_r($_POST); 

mysql_close();

?>
```